# Can't get Veelo style chapter number in memoir class

Tags: numbering, memoir, chapters

I take the Veelo chapter style code in p.399 [`memman.pdf`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir) and make slight change on fontsize and colour. When I compile, it prints the word "Chapter" without the chapter number. I have two questions:

1. Why doesn't it print the chapter number? Am I missing something?
2. How can I manually number the chapters? For example, make something like `\chapter[n]{ABC}` that prints "Chapter n: ABC"

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx, xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\numberheight}
\newlength{\barlength}
\makechapterstyle{veelo}{%
    \setlength{\afterchapskip}{40pt}
    \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\vspace*{40pt}}
    \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{\par\nobreak\vskip 25pt}
    \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont\LARGE\flushright\color{magenta}}
    \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\HUGE}
    \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\flushright\color{cyan}}
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{%
        \chapnamefont\scshape{\@chapapp}}
    \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
    \setlength{\beforechapskip}{18mm}
    \setlength{\midchapskip}{\paperwidth}
    \addtolength{\midchapskip}{-\textwidth}
    \addtolength{\midchapskip}{-\spinemargin}
    \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
        \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{.8em}%
            \resizebox{!}{\numberheight}{\chapnumfont\thechapter}%
            \hspace{.8em}%
            \rule{\midchapskip}{\beforechapskip}%
        }}%
    }
    \makeatother 
\chapterstyle{veelo}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Applications of the Derivative}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've resized the number to zero dimension.

```
\newlength{\numberheight}
```

Defines a length. By default, this is zero. Since you don't change it, you've made the number vanish. Replacing the default dimension, the number reappears, but you can obviously define `\numberheight` to whatever you intended and then replace it in your redefinition.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx, xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\numberheight}
\newlength{\barlength}
\makechapterstyle{veelo}{%
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{40pt}
  \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\vspace*{40pt}}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{\par\nobreak\vskip 25pt}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont\LARGE\flushright\color{magenta}}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\HUGE}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\flushright\color{cyan}}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{%
    \chapnamefont\scshape{\@chapapp}}
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{18mm}
  \setlength{\midchapskip}{\paperwidth}
  \addtolength{\midchapskip}{-\textwidth}
  \addtolength{\midchapskip}{-\spinemargin}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{.8em}%
      \resizebox{!}{\beforechapskip}{\chapnumfont \thechapter}%
      \hspace{.8em}%
      \rule{\midchapskip}{\beforechapskip}%
    }}%
}
\makeatother
\chapterstyle{veelo}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Applications of the Derivative}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: non-zero sized number]

To avoid confusion, I would recommend using a style name other than `veelo` since `veelo` is already defined. It will work this way, but it unnecessarily invites trouble down the line.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. What about the second question about numbering chapters manually? Have you got any idea?

Comment: @PhuocLuanDuong: To number a chapter as X, add `\setcounter{chapter}{Y}` where Y=X-1 just before `\chapter`.

Comment: @PhuocLuanDuong The site works best when you ask one question per ... well, per question, really. I can't imagine why you'd want manual numbering in general but Werner's comment above says how to do it.

Comment: @cfr Yep, Werner's solution fit me well. And the reason why I want manual numbering is that I'm making a demo chapter of my book, and since it is actually Chapter 3, I want to manually number it 3, not 1 by default.